# ActionBarSherlock: java.lang.IllegalStateException on very few Devices

Tags: android, exception, themes, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I got a very strange issue. Im using ActionbarSherlock in my project. And on very few Devices i get a:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.felitec.dow/de.felitec.dow.ui.LoginActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:976)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.installDecor(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:902)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:836)
at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.setContentView(SherlockActivity.java:229)
at de.felitec.dow.ui.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:36)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
... 11 more
```

My LoginActivity looks like this:

```
public class LoginActivity extends SherlockActivity implements AuthCallback<OAuthConsumer> {

    private ProgressDialog progDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
    }

...
```

And my Manifest:

```
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_app_launcher"
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:theme="@style/MainAppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.LoginActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
...
```

And finally my style.xml:

```
<style name="MainAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/back_indicator</item>
...
```

Notice that the SplashActivity works just fine. When it starts the intent for LoginActivity it crashes, and i dont really see why.

thanks in advance

Comment: LoginActivity.java line 36-- what is it?

Comment: if you look at the posted source and the stacktrace (one line above the line you saw) you'll see that 36 is the `setContentView(R.layout.login);`

Comment: @user1776342 try to use an explicit Sherlock Theme for your loginactivity. also can you state on which devices (android version) the error occurs and on which not? may be a bug in android framework. otherwise you should  file a issue on [ABS github](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock)

Comment: i sadly cannot say on which devices it occurs, since bugsense sdk doesent even recognize it. it looks like some user reported this (one of them from a GT-P6800) through the android error framework

Comment: so i added the theme **android:theme="@style/MainAppTheme"** and the problem persists

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have the same issue on the following devices: (Galaxy Tab 7.0 Plus (GT-P6200), XOOM (wifi_hubble) and GT-P7510)

Comment: I encountered this today. It seems like my project had a `values-v11` and a `values-v14` folder that contained incorrect base themes. Deleting these folders fixed this issue for devices running older versions of Android.

Answer (score 2):

Update your Manifiest file with this.

```
   android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"
```